# Python dataclasses: initialize and hide fields of superclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I would like to achieve that I can craete a sub-dataclass `B` from dataclass `A`, where `B` would initialize and thus hide fields from `A`:

```py
@dataclass
class A:
  a: str
  b: str

@dataclass
class B(A):
  c: str

  # not working! just showing, what i'd like to achive
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = f"extended-{c}"

test = B(b="foo", c="bar")  # <-- parameter 'a' should not be required and available

test.a  # "extended-bar"
test.b  # "foo"
test.c  # "bar"
```

Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 1):

Awesome - I think I've found a solution. This one works for my current case:

```py
@dataclass
class A:
  a: str
  b: str

@dataclass
class B(A):
  a: str = field(init=False)
  c: str

  def __post_init__(self) -> None:
    self.a = f"extended-{c}"
```